# I don't mind. It should be quite interesting!

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

It would be highly appreciated if someone tells me what the mean of the blow sentences is and gives me a paraphrase for each one:

> I don't mind. It should be quite interesting!

I want to know whether "it" is interesting or not. Indeed, I don't understand the meaning of the first section.
And what about the below sentence?

> I would not mind having a go at that!

Comment: "What is the meaning of the sentences below."

Comment: _I wouldn't mind_ is an idiom suggesting that you don't have a strong desire to do something, but since someone has suggested it you are willing to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentences "I don't mind. It should be quite interesting" mean that it doesn't matter to you, but you think that it will, for lack of a better word, interest you. To make the sentence smoother, you might insert an and or some other word to merge the sentences so that they are not so choppy. Also "it" refers to what you are talking about, so only you would know whether or not it is interesting. But based on the context of the sentence, I would believe that you have not yet tried it but believe that it would be interesting if you did try it.

I would not mind having a go at that, or as I would say it, I *wouldn't* mind having a go at that, means that you would like to try "that"; whatever someone is doing that you would like to have a go at or try.